# Java communication between objects using Uri

Tags: java, api, uri, communication

I am trying to get java objects (object1 and object2) to communicate using URIs. I would like these objects to have a Uri that has different endpoints and to execute some code when the URI is reached. The objects could be running on different computers (but on the same network) or locally on the same machine.

An example of this could be:
If object2 wants to enter object1 it could access something like "object1@localhost:80/service/enter?name=object2" . and object2 would get a reply saying {"Accept"} or {"Error:condition not met"}.

I am making libraries in this project so it can be imported as a jar file and it is being implemented on eclipse. Someone suggested I could have a server for each object and then create a REST API on that. Does anyone know how to do that?

I know it is a lot easier to use socket programming/RMI for direct calls but because of the scope of the project that is not possible.

Comment: I think you might be looking for something like RMI: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/hello/hello-world.html

Comment: Thank you for the comment but the reason they are designed to be URIs is that these objects can offer services to one another just like web-apis. That is why using URIs is an important requirement. Do you think it is possible to use URIs for this scenario?